# How to use rxjs map to filter out an observable list of object by another list of objects of different type

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I have an observable list that I'm returning from an api and i want to filter it base on a property value of another list that I have in local session storage. It's basically an inner join.
is there a better way than using rxjs map / filter?
This filter works for a single value but I'm not sure how to go about filtering it based on a property value of a list

```
 loadTable() {
    this.service.getSomeDataFromAPI() 
    .pipe(
      map(
        items => items.filter(item => item.branchCode.indexOf(StaticListOfObjects.branchCode) > -1)       
         )
     )
    .subscribe(response => {  ...  }
    );
  }
```

This is my staticListOfObject and I need to filter for all the objects that matches branchCode.

```js
[
  {
    branchCode: "AV1",
    summaryCount: 10,
  },
  {
    branchCode: "AV2",
    summaryCount: 5,
  },
  {
    branchCode: "BR1",
    summaryCount: 4,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API call returns a list (I presume an array) you just need to map it and filter it like so;

```
  let filterArray = [
  {
    branchCode: "AV1",
    summaryCount: 10
  },
  {
    branchCode: "AV2",
    summaryCount: 5
  },
  {
    branchCode: "BR1",
    summaryCount: 4
  }]

  loadTable() {
    this.service.getSomeDataFromAPI().pipe(
      map(
        items => items.filter( item => {
          if (filterArray.find(filterItem => filterItem.branchCode == item.branchCode)) {
            return true
          } else {
            return false
          }
        })   
      )
    ).subscribe(response => {  ...  });
  }
```

Comment: wow. thanks Sergey. this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Considering

```
const StaticListOfObjects = [
  {
    branchCode: "AV1",
    summaryCount: 10,
  },
  {
    branchCode: "AV2",
    summaryCount: 5,
  },
  {
    branchCode: "BR1",
    summaryCount: 4,
  },
];
```

another possible solution **if your observable completes after sending the first array** (and you are willing to use ES6) could be

```
loadTable() {
    const valid_values = StaticListOfObjects.map(x => x.branchCode);
    this.service.getSomeDataFromAPI() 
      .pipe(
        concatMap(y => y),
        filter(y => valid_value.includes(y.branchCode)),
        toArray(),
      )
      .subscribe(response => {  ...  }
 }
```

`concatMap` gets your array and emits observables of all its values, then you filter on each object with the `filter` operator and finally `toArray` bundles up all those filtered into an array when the observable returned by `getSomeDataFromAPI()` completes (this is the reason why it only works if the observable completes after emitting the first array, if it doesn't then the pipe will keep filtering newly emitted arrays until the observable completes returning all filtered values from all received source arrays into a single result array).

Comment: would that use a lot of resources if the array/observable gets too large? thanks for the help